# PDFBox handling of hidden / invisible text ？

Tags: java

Some people will hide part of the text under the picture when editing the PDF file, but when I extract the content of this pdf file through PDFBox, I will get all the content. Does PDFBox have the concept of cascading？I want to filter out this content.

Comment: It is an interesting question. May I suggest editing the title to a clearer text, e.g. "PDFBox handling of hidden / invisible text" ? Furthermore, you state the example of text that is "hidden" under a picture, but you also have the case of transparent text (no stroking, no filling), and invisible text (white text on a white background). Does that interest you too ?

Comment: Thanks for your  suggestion. In fact, I also encountered another problem, e.g."Part of the content is outside the page(because this pdf file is converted from word)", you can judge whether it is in the page by the coordinates of char.

Comment: This way may produce a new problem, some pdf files need to be kept outside the page, because this is caused by a file conversion error. Some content outside the pdf file page needs to be filtered out, because they are advertisements or other unrelated content. You can judge whether it is continuous by calculating the coordinate interval. This way can filter out a lot of irrelevant content, while retaining what you want.